# How do I do a Django query on a Model, where I order by field A, but filter distinct on field B?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

Suppose I have a Book table, where each book has an author field and a publishing date field.

I would like to get the latest book by each author. I'm using PostgreSQL as the backend.

The obvious (and wrong) solution would be:

```
Book.objects.order_by("author", "-published_on").distinct("author").all()
```

The problem is that while the result contains only one book from each author, then there is no guarantee that it is the latest book. This might be because I'm using random UUIDs as PKs. I can't change that. That's a requirement.

The next obvious (and wrong) solution would be:

```
Book.objects.order_by("author", "-published_on").distinct("author", "published_on").all()
```

Here the ordering of the books is correct, but we get multiple books from the same author.

I have also tried flipping around the arguments:

```
Book.objects.order_by("-published_on", "author").distinct("published_on", "author").all()
```

Here the ordering of the books is correct, but we get multiple books from the same author.

How do I do a Django ORM query, where I get the latest book from each author?

EDIT: Here's a query I'm actually running on our live DB, before translating it into the book-style example:

```
from db.models import User, EventVisibility
user = User.objects.get(username="7g8jltdzbz46ak7nhuz8tzfuu7y9mdym7tiy7klfxjnn")
evs = EventVisibility.objects.filter(user=user).order_by("room", "-created_on").distinct("room")[:20]
for ev in evs:
    print(f"book_id={ev.room.room_id}, published_on={ev.created_on}")
```

And these are the results:

```
book_id=2mcnhajfwf5jsgyzpqix36ytbjfucn9u6derkyurlfff, published_on=2020-05-16 00:54:05.083477+00:00
book_id=4rp9ffxqr5marnphbtlahqtwnkzozupyb8ht532ffxl6, published_on=2020-05-12 20:29:31.286095+00:00
book_id=5dqygkksrzq6ay49xxcspagma5cbz8p59sjcavf6pepm, published_on=2020-05-08 09:28:53.508563+00:00
book_id=9mz85qcxreaczcnenebcywqqm3scehjhpwlkso7g4jbd, published_on=2020-05-04 10:52:06.396995+00:00
book_id=9sgiiasbvbtat4iahx7bd7ammzwatgfipe8wmzl9snz5, published_on=2020-05-15 09:00:52.602512+00:00
book_id=b8uvcxuhgjhmvkjjnwkcr5zzj7hrushz2e9mpzkosg8k, published_on=2020-05-08 09:36:47.148885+00:00
book_id=bxif8aal2v4fb3p8wsdvdard5p65ygw8j92tnleqqza4, published_on=2020-04-19 02:43:23.819854+00:00
book_id=cgoad7xuwjhxz6hcxctbl5arnnsrjt5osuwmzunmppra, published_on=2020-05-08 09:36:06.944614+00:00
book_id=cztb84akqqde6fvpj2nneqezvmor5gdjh3hpcjnxcz2x, published_on=2020-05-15 10:06:53.054862+00:00
book_id=czxizxptbvxz7jybkxevk2mkmaxykhgakfluud7ffa2b, published_on=2020-05-17 14:54:43.245325+00:00
book_id=dgtze2ri5snrr7nmurvdechydxjd2ph3dd8rugibn2me, published_on=2020-05-05 19:16:45.254928+00:00
book_id=dp9wu8qmdw6prsvx2zwvrnw5akcxv6llcwa2skeadcpx, published_on=2020-04-27 10:58:32.555542+00:00
book_id=duelfazwfiek8jhr4ew7wa9vrzzuyhznzxcrpybmbuww, published_on=2020-05-15 10:06:45.001961+00:00
book_id=dwhqxqfyolggdf5wwwm3su3yq6ffsh5kwwjxj7wtkdbj, published_on=2020-05-15 05:53:01.153492+00:00
book_id=edakxxhqv7w99lukxr23dfugcarddpwj5ea8wx7r5bmd, published_on=2020-04-27 19:49:29.673872+00:00
book_id=evz9biehu88eds7hgcutw6jfktt4fkjznfgozxsu8jtk, published_on=2020-04-20 21:13:01.693752+00:00
book_id=fqnxa3j4vbbaw7fc5hgrumabtfh2phmd3hg7cgm5ayfa, published_on=2020-05-15 10:04:22.322094+00:00
book_id=gkxahh8y7eqtqzxsnjtdpnghxnipi8vx3qugjcrs6t3m, published_on=2020-04-17 02:14:31.219950+00:00
book_id=hdgoxpnmqde8siwdbgfwwtodqk4hzhefyz8pw3esdmem, published_on=2020-05-17 14:46:49.437289+00:00
book_id=jrg6uae5kyvfvjgjhmwvzf45lbtqmgspawbuqzfewnhc, published_on=2020-05-05 09:11:59.334099+00:00
```

This is the `queryset.query`:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON ("db_eventvisibility"."room_id") "db_eventvisibility"."id", "db_eventvisibility"."event_id", "db_eventvisibility"."user_id", "db_eventvisibility"."room_id", "db_eventvisibility"."unit_id", "db_eventvisibility"."case_id", "db_eventvisibility"."team_id", "db_eventvisibility"."created_on" FROM "db_eventvisibility" WHERE "db_eventvisibility"."user_id" = 7g8jltdzbz46ak7nhuz8tzfuu7y9mdym7tiy7klfxjnn ORDER BY "db_eventvisibility"."room_id" ASC, "db_eventvisibility"."created_on" DESC LIMIT 20`

Comment: Actually there *is* a guarantee, since if you `.order_by()` also includes the `published_on`, then it will always take the first one.

Comment: I thought so, too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: well the documentation says: "*For example, `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a)` gives you the **first row** for each value in column a. If you don’t specify an order, you’ll get some arbitrary row.*". This is PostgreSQL specific, so I would expect, given the documentation, and the behavior of PgSQL did not change, that that would work.

Comment: You can see the query Django generates with `print(queryset.query)`. Perhaps you made for example some object manager that introduces some problems in the query.

Comment: Is it possible to [edit] the question and show the query the Django ORM generates?

Comment: Edited to add example from live db.

Comment: I think the result can still be correct. What you get is the latest booking *per room*, but the set of rooms is *not* ordered by the latest booking, but by its UUID, but that does not mean that the `published_on` *per* book/event is not the latest one. So the timings appear "random", but are each the *latest* per room.

Comment: Ran the same code on another deployment on another machine and got the same result: unique book_id's, but completely random timestamp ordering.

Comment: If you however wish to sort the `Room`s per latest booking, then you do that with another query.

Comment: I do wish to sort the returned rooms by latest timestamp. How do I do that?

Comment: @Harben: you can not do that, since the `.distinct()` requires to be the fields in the `.distinct()` to be *first* in the `.order_by()`, this is a requirement by PostgreSQL since it allows fast uniqness filtering.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that while the result contains only one book from each author, then there is **no guarantee that it is the latest book**. This might be because I'm using random UUIDs as PKs. I can't change that. That's a requirement.

To the best of my knowledge, the result is correct in the sense that *per* `Room`, you get indeed the latest `EventVisibility`, but likely that is not what you want. If you want to sort the `Room`s per latest `EventVisibility`, then you can do that with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Room.objects.filter(
    eventvisibility__user=user
).order_by(
    Max('eventvisibitility__created_on').desc()
)
```